# Does existence of the derivative along a curve imply existence of the directional derivative?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I am facing the following situation:

Let $c: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be at least $C^1$-curve and $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous function (or maybe an homeomorphism).
If one knows that $(F \circ c)'(t_0)$ exists for some $t_0$, can we deduce that the directional derivative of $F$ at the point $c(t_0)$ in the direction of $c'(t_0)$ exists?

In other words assuming $t_0=0, c(0)=0=F(0)$:
$(F \circ c)'(0) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(c(0)+h c'(0) + O(h^2))}{h} \overset?= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(c(0)+h c'(0))}{h} = D_{c'(0)} F (0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just continuity isn't enough. I'll give a counterexample $G\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ first; then you can take $F(x,y)=(G(x,y),y)$ to get $F\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

For $x \neq 0$, let
$$
G(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $|y| \ge x^2$}
,\\
x(1-|y|/x^2), & \text{if $|y| < x^2$}
,
\end{cases}
$$
That is, for each fixed $x\neq 0$, the function $y \mapsto G(x,y)$ is a piecewise linear “tent function” with a peak of height $x$ (or a trough, if $x<0$) and support on the interval $-x^2 \le y \le x^2$.
This tends uniformly to zero as $x \to 0$, so if we also set $G(0,y)=0$ we get a continuous function $G$.

Now, $G(x,0)=x$ for all $x$, so the directional derivative in the $x$ direction at the origin equals $1$.

But on the parabola $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$, which passes through the origin in the $x$ direction, we have $G(t,t^2)=0$, so the derivative along that curve isn't equal to the directional derivative.